# Error #1064 from MySQL searching database for results near lat/long

Tags: sql, query, mysql-spatial

I'm trying to run a SQL query to search for a term and a users location. I need help to search my database for locations near a user with the description of 'X'. The users location (lat, long) is drawn when they click 'find' on a form for 'X'.

Individually each query works fine. I can find all with a specific %search_term% using:

```
 SELECT * FROM  `table_name` WHERE  `column_name` LIKE '%search_term%'
```

and also find all the locations from the distant of the user using:

```
  SELECT *, (
  3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians($lat) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($long) )
  + sin ( radians($lat) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
  )
  ) AS distance
  FROM locations
  HAVING distance < 50
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

but together I receive an error #1064.

This is the query:

```
  SELECT * FROM  `table_name` WHERE  `column_name` LIKE '%search_term%' AND 
  *, (
  3959 * acos (
  cos ( radians($lat) )
  * cos( radians( lat ) )
  * cos( radians( lng ) - radians($long) )
  + sin ( radians($lat) )
  * sin( radians( lat ) )
  )
  ) AS distance
  FROM locations
  HAVING distance < 50
  ORDER BY distance
  LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Comment: `LIMIT 0`? Doesn't that mean return nothing?

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup, I used the initial SELECT statement from Google here: [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)
The full code is 
    'LIMIT 0 , 20;' The error only listed 'LIMIT 0 ,'

Comment: I think that's shorthand for `LIMIT 0 OFFSET 20` (i.e. returning no rows, starting from row 20). I don't really understand the syntax or why that would be useful; have you tried just with `LIMIT 10` or something?

Comment: @alpha-beta-soup, i edited my question to try to be more specific. The LIMIT 0 , 20 isn't a problem when I separate the SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1064 means syntax error. You are putting "AS distance" at wrong place. Try this:

```
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos (radians($lat))*cos(radians(lat))*cos(radians(lng) - radians($long))+sin (radians($lat))*sin( radians( lat ) )  )  ) AS distance FROM  `table_name` WHERE `column_name` LIKE '%search_term%' HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance  LIMIT 0 , 20;
```